# Which button do I "HOLD" in Mission 33

Tags: pc, far-cry-3

When I get to the torture scene, I'm prompted to hit left mouse twice to throw two punches at the prisoner.  When it's time to jam my thumb into his wound, all is see is `HOLD` but no button prompt.  I don't have any keys unbound and nothing seems to work.  So now I'm stuck at this point.  What am I supposed to press?

Comment: Does holding down your left mouse button work?

Comment: From memory, I think it was "E" or interact if you're on a console...

Answer (score 1):

By default, it should be the spacebar.

Comment: Played this yesterday and I can confirm it's space.